# Why are the functions ambiguous?

Tags: c++

When compiling a sample code on g++ (v4.7.3), got error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 te2b.cc
te2b.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
te2b.cc:17:19: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
te2b.cc:10:6: note: candidate 1: void notify(std::string, int)
te2b.cc:7:6: note: candidate 2: void notify(const char*, ...)
```

The following is sample code.  Don't see why the ambiguity: the compiler should know to map call to `notify()` in `main()` to the first declaration. `void notify(const char *fmt, ...)`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdarg.h>
using namespace std;
char notifyBuf[0x100000] = "\x06\x00\x00\x00" "notify""s";
void notify(const char *fmt, ...) {
    //....
}
void notify(string s, int maxSize = 0) {
    if (maxSize && (maxSize < s.size())) {
        s.erase(maxSize);
    }
    notify("%s\n", s.c_str());
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    notify("%5d ", 89);    
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Did you Google its text? This has been answered many times.

Comment: @Niall array to pointer is a standard conversion sequence, the other you mention is user-defined, so... no, not this one is ambiguous. `89` is an exact match for `int`, while `const char*` is better for a raw string literal than `std::string`

Comment: @Niall: Even when use use explicitly `const char*`, it is ambiguous [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2139662dc197a73)

Comment: Thanks guys for the discussion.  Agree it's a warning, but in my testing, it always refers to the second declaration `void notify(string s, int maxSize = 0)`.  Wonder if there is a way to call the first declaration in `main()`.  Thanks.

Comment: @codingFun Yes, switch the order of the arguments on the second function to be (int, string)

Comment: Any reason to use ellipsis `...` instead of variadic template ?

Comment: @dietbacon, don't think it's legal to do `void notify(int maxSize = 0, string s )`. Thx anyway.

Comment: @Jarod42, no particular reason to use ellipsis.  All I need to do is to be able to invoke any of the two declarations in application (`main()`).    How would you rewrite the declaration based on variadic template?

Comment: @codingFun: Something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff98f057680584d2)

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks for the link. It solves my problem.  Could you write it up as an answer?

Comment: It fixes your problem, but doesn't answer your question, so I don't convert my comment in answer.

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

§ 13.3.3 [over.match.best]/p2:

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   F2 if **for all arguments i, ICS<sub>i</sub>(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence** than ICS<sub>i</sub>(F2), and then
>
> <sup>(1.3)</sup> — for some argument j, ICS<sub>j</sub>(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICS<sub>j</sub>(F2), or, if not that, [...]

Given function call `notify("%5d ", 89);` and two overloads:

```
void notify(const char*, ...);   // F1
void notify(std::string, int);   // F2
```

the compiler has the following set of implicit conversion sequences for the arguments of `F1`:

- ICS<sub>0</sub>(F1) - a standard conversion sequence (an array to pointer conversion)
- ICS<sub>1</sub>(F1) - an ellipsis conversion sequence

and the following set of implicit conversion sequences for the arguments of `F2`:

- ICS<sub>0</sub>(F2) - a user defined conversion sequence (via a constructor)
- ICS<sub>1</sub>(F2) - a standard conversion sequence (an identity conversion)

Because ICS<sub>0</sub>(F1) is better than ICS<sub>0</sub>(F2), but, in turn, ICS<sub>1</sub>(F2) is better than ICS<sub>1</sub>(F1), the compiler can't choose between the two.*

---

* § 13.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank]/p2:

> When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as defined in 13.3.3.1):
>
> — a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and
>
> — a user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion sequence than an ellipsis conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

Comment: Wish there is a way to tell compiler to use dictionary order for a particular function name (`notify` in this case) :-)